# I'm having an error while deploying my app in heroku

Tags: heroku

ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
command: /app/.heroku/python/bin/python /app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pep517/_in_process.py prepare_metadata_for_build_wheel /tmp/tmp3b4z4ntu
cwd: /tmp/pip-install-1m_e8096/scipy
Complete output (171 lines):
setup.py:460: UserWarning: Unrecognized setuptools command ('dist_info --egg-base /tmp/pip-modern-metadata-v__rgpzs'), proceeding with generating Cython sources and expanding templates
warnings.warn("Unrecognized setuptools command ('{}'), proceeding with "
Running from SciPy source directory.
lapack_opt_info:
lapack_mkl_info:
customize UnixCCompiler
libraries mkl_rt not found in ['/app/.heroku/python/lib', '/usr/local/lib', '/usr/lib64', '/usr/lib', '/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu']
NOT AVAILABLE

```
       openblas_lapack_info:
       customize UnixCCompiler
       customize UnixCCompiler
         libraries openblas not found in ['/app/.heroku/python/lib', '/usr/local/lib', '/usr/lib64', '/usr/lib', '/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu']
         NOT AVAILABLE
       
       openblas_clapack_info:
       customize UnixCCompiler
       customize UnixCCompiler
         libraries openblas,lapack not found in ['/app/.heroku/python/lib', '/usr/local/lib', '/usr/lib64', '/usr/lib', '/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu']
         NOT AVAILABLE
       
       flame_info:
       customize UnixCCompiler
         libraries flame not found in ['/app/.heroku/python/lib', '/usr/local/lib', '/usr/lib64', '/usr/lib', '/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu']
         NOT AVAILABLE
       
       atlas_3_10_threads_info:
       Setting PTATLAS=ATLAS
       customize UnixCCompiler
         libraries lapack_atlas not found in /app/.heroku/python/lib
       customize UnixCCompiler
         libraries tatlas,tatlas not found in /app/.heroku/python/lib
       customize UnixCCompiler
         libraries lapack_atlas not found in /usr/local/lib
       customize UnixCCompiler
         libraries tatlas,tatlas not found in /usr/local/lib
       customize UnixCCompiler
         libraries lapack_atlas not found in /usr/lib64
       customize UnixCCompiler
         libraries tatlas,tatlas not found in /usr/lib64
       customize UnixCCompiler
         libraries lapack_atlas not found in /usr/lib
       customize UnixCCompiler
         libraries tatlas,tatlas not found in /usr/lib
       customize UnixCCompiler
         libraries lapack_atlas not found in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu
       customize UnixCCompiler
         libraries tatlas,tatlas not found in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu
       <class 'numpy.distutils.system_info.atlas_3_10_threads_info'>
         NOT AVAILABLE
       
       atlas_3_10_info:
       customize UnixCCompiler
         libraries lapack_atlas not found in /app/.heroku/python/lib
       customize UnixCCompiler
         libraries satlas,satlas not found in /app/.heroku/python/lib
       customize UnixCCompiler
         libraries lapack_atlas not found in /usr/local/lib
       customize UnixCCompiler
         libraries satlas,satlas not found in /usr/local/lib
       customize UnixCCompiler
         libraries lapack_atlas not found in /usr/lib64
       customize UnixCCompiler
         libraries satlas,satlas not found in /usr/lib64
       customize UnixCCompiler
         libraries lapack_atlas not found in /usr/lib
       customize UnixCCompiler
         libraries satlas,satlas not found in /usr/lib
       customize UnixCCompiler
         libraries lapack_atlas not found in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu
       customize UnixCCompiler
         libraries satlas,satlas not found in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu
       <class 'numpy.distutils.system_info.atlas_3_10_info'>
         NOT AVAILABLE
       
       atlas_threads_info:
       Setting PTATLAS=ATLAS
       customize UnixCCompiler
         libraries lapack_atlas not found in /app/.heroku/python/lib
       customize UnixCCompiler
         libraries ptf77blas,ptcblas,atlas not found in /app/.heroku/python/lib
       customize UnixCCompiler
         libraries lapack_atlas not found in /usr/local/lib
       customize UnixCCompiler
         libraries ptf77blas,ptcblas,atlas not found in /usr/local/lib
       customize UnixCCompiler
         libraries lapack_atlas not found in /usr/lib64
       customize UnixCCompiler
         libraries ptf77blas,ptcblas,atlas not found in /usr/lib64
       customize UnixCCompiler
         libraries lapack_atlas not found in /usr/lib
       customize UnixCCompiler
         libraries ptf77blas,ptcblas,atlas not found in /usr/lib
       customize UnixCCompiler
         libraries lapack_atlas not found in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu
       customize UnixCCompiler
         libraries ptf77blas,ptcblas,atlas not found in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu
       <class 'numpy.distutils.system_info.atlas_threads_info'>
         NOT AVAILABLE
       
       atlas_info:
       customize UnixCCompiler
         libraries lapack_atlas not found in /app/.heroku/python/lib
       customize UnixCCompiler
         libraries f77blas,cblas,atlas not found in /app/.heroku/python/lib
       customize UnixCCompiler
         libraries lapack_atlas not found in /usr/local/lib
       customize UnixCCompiler
         libraries f77blas,cblas,atlas not found in /usr/local/lib
       customize UnixCCompiler
         libraries lapack_atlas not found in /usr/lib64
       customize UnixCCompiler
         libraries f77blas,cblas,atlas not found in /usr/lib64
       customize UnixCCompiler
         libraries lapack_atlas not found in /usr/lib
       customize UnixCCompiler
         libraries f77blas,cblas,atlas not found in /usr/lib
       customize UnixCCompiler
         libraries lapack_atlas not found in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu
       customize UnixCCompiler
         libraries f77blas,cblas,atlas not found in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu
       <class 'numpy.distutils.system_info.atlas_info'>
         NOT AVAILABLE
       
       accelerate_info:
         NOT AVAILABLE
       
       lapack_info:
       customize UnixCCompiler
         libraries lapack not found in ['/app/.heroku/python/lib', '/usr/local/lib', '/usr/lib64', '/usr/lib', '/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu']
         NOT AVAILABLE
       
       /tmp/pip-build-env-k61l7gdq/overlay/lib/python3.9/site-packages/numpy/distutils/system_info.py:1712: UserWarning:
           Lapack (http://www.netlib.org/lapack/) libraries not found.
           Directories to search for the libraries can be specified in the
           numpy/distutils/site.cfg file (section [lapack]) or by setting
           the LAPACK environment variable.
         if getattr(self, '_calc_info_{}'.format(lapack))():
       lapack_src_info:
         NOT AVAILABLE
       
       /tmp/pip-build-env-k61l7gdq/overlay/lib/python3.9/site-packages/numpy/distutils/system_info.py:1712: UserWarning:
           Lapack (http://www.netlib.org/lapack/) sources not found.
           Directories to search for the sources can be specified in the
           numpy/distutils/site.cfg file (section [lapack_src]) or by setting
           the LAPACK_SRC environment variable.
         if getattr(self, '_calc_info_{}'.format(lapack))():
         NOT AVAILABLE
       
       Traceback (most recent call last):
         File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pep517/_in_process.py", line 280, in <module>
           main()
         File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pep517/_in_process.py", line 263, in main
           json_out['return_val'] = hook(**hook_input['kwargs'])
         File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pep517/_in_process.py", line 133, in prepare_metadata_for_build_wheel
           return hook(metadata_directory, config_settings)
         File "/tmp/pip-build-env-k61l7gdq/overlay/lib/python3.9/site-packages/setuptools/build_meta.py", line 166, in prepare_metadata_for_build_wheel
           self.run_setup()
         File "/tmp/pip-build-env-k61l7gdq/overlay/lib/python3.9/site-packages/setuptools/build_meta.py", line 258, in run_setup
           super(_BuildMetaLegacyBackend,
         File "/tmp/pip-build-env-k61l7gdq/overlay/lib/python3.9/site-packages/setuptools/build_meta.py", line 150, in run_setup
           exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'), locals())
         File "setup.py", line 583, in <module>
           setup_package()
         File "setup.py", line 579, in setup_package
           setup(**metadata)
         File "/tmp/pip-build-env-k61l7gdq/overlay/lib/python3.9/site-packages/numpy/distutils/core.py", line 137, in setup
           config = configuration()
         File "setup.py", line 477, in configuration
           raise NotFoundError(msg)
       numpy.distutils.system_info.NotFoundError: No lapack/blas resources found.
       ----------------------------------------
   ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: /app/.heroku/python/bin/python /app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pep517/_in_process.py prepare_metadata_for_build_wheel /tmp/tmp3b4z4ntu Check the logs for full command output.
```

!     Push rejected, failed to compile Python app.
!     Push failed

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem changing the version of python. To change the version you have to follow the following steps.

1. Add a file "runtime.txt".
2. Edit runtime.txt and add "python-3.7.11" or other python version supported by heroku [python versions](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/python-support#specifying-a-python-version).
3. Push your changes to heroku, "git push heroku master"

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem by using `pipreqs` instead of `pip3 freeze > requirements.txt`.

**Why not pip freeze?**

1. `pip freeze` only saves the packages that are installed with `pip install` in your environment.
2. `pip freeze` saves all packages in the environment including those that you don't use in your current project. (if you don't have virtualenv)
3. and sometimes you just need to create requirements.txt for a new project without installing modules.